# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 - kafka storm integration

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am working on kafka strom integration. Im stuck with an error. The Build Fails when I try to Run it using
`mvn -e -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=storm.starter.MainTopology`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java  
(default-cli) on project storm-starter: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal 
 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid
```

This is a snippet of the pom.xml file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
      <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
      <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
      <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/
mvn clean install
```

I am using storm-0.9.0-rc3 and kafka-0.7.2

Comment: where are you setting `storm.topology` and to what value?

Comment: i am very new to programming.. setting value to storm topology means?..

Comment: is it a version mismatch problem? I am using org.codehaus.mojo version1.2.1

Comment: Are you on Windows machine + PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element mainClass is empty because the property storm.topology has no value, this is why you get an error.

You have to pass the storm.topology parameter instead of mainClass :

```
mvn -e -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.MainTopology
```

See the Maven section of the readme of this example for more information: 
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try adding this line

```
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- Add this -->
    <goals>
        .....
        .....
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I think that package was not needed in my project. I deleted it and now its working